# jQuery plugin for auto-completing AND dropdown functionality?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, jquery-autocomplete

I have a list of countries in a database. To allow users to select their country, I would like to implement a form that supports auto-complete / autofill AND "normal dropdown behavior" within one control. By auto-complete / autofill I mean that the user starts typing their country name and then a list of suggestions appears automatically based on what they entered for them to quickly select from - just like how the tags input box on this page works.

Examples can be seen on http://www.momondo.com/ and http://badoo.com/ but I think their script is custom.

Is there an opensource .js plugin for this that's cross-browser friendly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**JQueryUI Autocomplete** plugin is what you need http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

You can find a lot of demos and documentation in the previous link. I hope it helps you!